Grid Fill doesnt work

When I try to use Grid Fill, the window appears, but it doesn't fill my model.
Video

are these edges even connected? try selecting them, then using M > Merge by distance.

Please show an image of the complete Blender window in Vertex mode so that we can see the number of vertices in your selection. Use Blender's built-in screenshot generator via the Window > Save Screenshot menu, Edit your question and add the image to it.

Well, I cannot be 100% sure from what you've shown in that video but I'd wager a fair sum that the edges you had selected did not form a single closed loop with an even number of points.
It's not entirely clear from the documentation that you need an even number of points and I've run into this problem before.
Try subdividing one of the edges
